# Django Integration with SOLR and NUTCH

Tags: django, solr, nutch

I am using SOLR with NUTCH

I have successfully configure both and Solr is giving me the desired results

Now i want to integrate this in my Django project

Can anyone suggest me  how to do it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on what you need:

**IF YOUR SOLR INSTANCE IS BOUND TO THE DJANGO'S MODEL**

you probably are looking for [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/): it's pretty easy to setup and to use inside your django views, but it's not suited for huge amount of data

**IF YOU'RE USING SOLR WITHOUT ANY RELATION TO DJANGO MODELS**

this means that your results are retrieved as pure array, and you just need a python interface to solr. you have some choices

- [pysolr](http://code.google.com/p/pysolr/)
- [solrpy](http://code.google.com/p/solrpy/)
- [sunburnt](https://github.com/tow/sunburnt) (i'm using this)

you have to try them out and find out which one satisfies you more (check their websites too, to see if the project is mantained. also, stumble into their source code, to check if there's all you need). being a python interface implies that you have to do a little bit more of work inside your views

i hope this can help you